# Tuned 3 parameters using grid search but the best_estimator_ has only 2 parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation, grid-search

I am tuning a gradient boosted classifier using a pipeline and grid search

My pipeline is

```
pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(with_std=True, with_mean=True), \
    RFE(RandomForestClassifier(), n_features_to_select= 15), \
        GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=42, verbose=True))
```

The parameter gri is:

```
    tuned_parameters = [{'gradientboostingclassifier__max_depth': range(3, 5),\
'gradientboostingclassifier__min_samples_split': range(4,6),\
'gradientboostingclassifier__learning_rate':np.linspace(0.1, 1, 10)}]
```

The grid search is done as

```
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, tuned_parameters, cv=5, scoring='accuracy', refit=True)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After fitting the model in train data, when I check the `grid.best_estimator` I can only find the 2 parameters(`learning_rate and  min_samples_split` )that I am fitting. I don't find the `max_depth` parameter in the best estimator.

```
grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['gradientboostingclassifier'] =

GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.9, min_samples_split=5,
                           random_state=42, verbose=True)
```

But, if I use the `grid.cv_results` to find the best '`mean_test_score`' and find the corresponding parameters for that test score, then I can find the `max_depth` in it.

```
inde = np.where(grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score'] == max(grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']))

    grid.cv_results_['params'][inde[-1][0]]
{'gradientboostingclas...rning_rate': 0.9, 'gradientboostingclas..._max_depth': 3, 'gradientboostingclas...ples_split': 5}
special variables
function variables
'gradientboostingclassifier__learning_rate':0.9
'gradientboostingclassifier__max_depth':3
'gradientboostingclassifier__min_samples_split':5
```

My doubt now is, if I use the trained pipeline (name of the object is 'grid' in my case) will it still use the '`max_depth`' parameter also or will it not?
Is it then better to use the '`best parameters`' which gave me the best '`mean_test_score`' taken from the `grid.cv_results`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline has been tuned on all three parameters that you specified. It is just that the best value for `max_depth` happens to be the default value. When printing the classifier, default values will not be included. Compare the following outputs:

```py
print(GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=3)) # default
# output: GradientBoostingClassifier()

print(GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=5)) # not default
# output: GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=5)
```

In general, it is best-practice to access the best parameters by the `best_params_` attribute of the fitted `GridSearchCV` object since this will always include all parameters:

```py
grid.best_params_
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem when looking at the results of a GridSearchCV

the code I used

```
xgb_regressor = xgboost.XGBRegressor()

parameters_grid = {
    'max_depth': [4,8,9],
    'learning_rate': [0.01,0.1,0.2],
    'gamma': [0.1,0.25, 0.5, 0.7],
    'min_child_weight': [ 4, 5,6,7],
    'reg_lambda': [0.1, 0.3,0.5, 1, 5],
    'n_estimators': [60,70,80,90]
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=xgb_regressor,
    param_grid=parameters_grid,
    n_jobs = 10,
    cv = 10,
    verbose=True
)

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

grid_search.best_estimator_
```

It got me a long list without reg_lambda (notes there were "...")

```
XGBRegressor(base_score=None, booster=None, callbacks=None,
         colsample_bylevel=None, colsample_bynode=None,
         colsample_bytree=None, early_stopping_rounds=None,
         enable_categorical=False, eval_metric=None, feature_types=None,
         gamma=0.7, gpu_id=None, grow_policy=None, importance_type=None,
         interaction_constraints=None, learning_rate=0.2, max_bin=None,
         max_cat_threshold=None, max_cat_to_onehot=None,
         max_delta_step=None, max_depth=9, max_leaves=None,
         min_child_weight=4, missing=nan, monotone_constraints=None,
         n_estimators=90, n_jobs=None, num_parallel_tree=None,
         predictor=None, random_state=None, ...)
```

I found the way to see the value that did not display

```
grid_search.best_estimator_.reg_lambda
```

printed the tuned value I was looking for.

Comment: Is the tuned value that got printed the same as the default value?

Comment: No. the tuned value printed was 5. The default=1/0 (depends on the booster) @thileepan